# Find and replace in a document from a list of replacements?

Tags: regex, perl

Using Perl to replace from a list of regexes that are replacements.

I do have this kind of list to perform replacements but I  got a list of more than 50.000 and I really got a "stack overflow" message in the app I  am using, always out of memory.

```
(.*zaz\s+=\s.*z)ª(z$)               \1a\2
(.*zaz\s+=\s.*z)ª(s$)               \1a\2
(.*zaz\s+=\s.*s)ª(z$)               \1a\2
(.*zaz\s+=\s.*s)ª(s$)               \1a\2
(.*zay\s+=\s.*z)ª(y$)               \1a\2
(.*zay\s+=\s.*s)ª(y$)               \1a\2
(.*zax\s+=\s.*z)ª(k$)               \1a\2
(.*zax\s+=\s.*s)ª(k$)               \1a\2
(.*zaw\s+=\s.*z)ª(w$)               \1a\2
(.*zaw\s+=\s.*z)ª(v$)               \1a\2
(.*zaw\s+=\s.*s)ª(w$)               \1a\2
(.*zaw\s+=\s.*s)ª(v$)               \1a\2
(.*zav\s+=\s.*z)ª(v$)               \1a\2
(.*zav\s+=\s.*s)ª(v$)               \1a\2
(.*zat\s+=\s.*z)ª(t$)               \1a\2
(.*zat\s+=\s.*s)ª(t$)               \1a\2
(.*zas\s+=\s.*z)ª(z$)               \1a\2
(.*zas\s+=\s.*z)ª(s$)               \1a\2
(.*zas\s+=\s.*s)ª(z$)               \1a\2
(.*zas\s+=\s.*s)ª(s$)               \1a\2
(.*zar\s+=\s.*z)ª(r$)               \1a\2
(.*zar\s+=\s.*s)ª(r$)               \1a\2
(.*zaq\s+=\s.*z)ª(q$)               \1a\2
(.*zaq\s+=\s.*z)ª(k$)               \1a\2
(.*zaq\s+=\s.*z)ª(c$)               \1a\2
(.*zaq\s+=\s.*s)ª(q$)               \1a\2
(.*zaq\s+=\s.*s)ª(k$)               \1a\2
(.*zaq\s+=\s.*s)ª(c$)               \1a\2
```

On the left side the Regex to perform and on the right side the replacement.
I would like to achieve this in Perl.
The search and replace is always in a unique document.

As you can see, i am trying to replace the "ª" caracter but always under certain circumstances, sometimes the replacement should be "a" or "e" or "i" or "o", so that is why the list is so huge, since is trying many possibilities.

Comment: Can you give some examples of the types of data you want to match and correct to?

Answer (score 0):

It will take a long time, but you can perform the replacements several by several.  You can store the list of Regexes in the file and read only a manageable number of Regexes at a time from the file, going over the documents you're performing the replacements on once per each set of Regexes.

Answer (score 0):

Many of these regular expressions can be combined using character classes. For example, these 8 regular expressions:

```
(.*zaz\s+=\s.*z)ª(z$)               \1a\2
(.*zaz\s+=\s.*z)ª(s$)               \1a\2
(.*zaz\s+=\s.*s)ª(z$)               \1a\2
(.*zaz\s+=\s.*s)ª(s$)               \1a\2
(.*zas\s+=\s.*z)ª(z$)               \1a\2
(.*zas\s+=\s.*z)ª(s$)               \1a\2
(.*zas\s+=\s.*s)ª(z$)               \1a\2
(.*zas\s+=\s.*s)ª(s$)               \1a\2
```

could be replaced by:

```
(.*za[sz]\s+=\s.*[sz])ª([sz]$)      \1a\2
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to make multiple replacements:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = 'input.txt';
my $newfile = 'new_blah.txt';

open my $infh, '<', $file;
open my $outfh, '>', $newfile;

while (my $line = <$infh>) {
# Any manipulation to $line here, such as that regex:
$line =~ s/e/i/gm;
$line =~ s/t/zzz/gm;

print $outfh $line;
}

close $infh;
close $outfh;
```

There where says : $line =~ , the part for writing the regex is : ///  whith modifiers look like this s///mg and take a look where is the search and the replace fields an s/**search**/**replace**/gm;  so every time that you write a different regex, it goes 1 by 1.
In the above example we are replacing "e" for "i" then the next regex is change "t" for "zzz"

I am kind of sad, that a simple answer couldn't be given.